# Nginx url rewrite through dispatcher.php

Tags: php, nginx, redirect, digital-ocean

I have a problem with Nginx .conf and redirection.

I have the following dispatcher.php:

```
<?
$routes = array(
    ''          => 'index.php',
    'story'     => 'story.php',
    'submit'    => 'submit.php',
    'subedit'   => 'subedit.php',
);

$globals['path'] = $path = preg_split('/\/+/', $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'], 10, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
$script = $routes[$path[0]];

if (empty($script) || !file_exists($script)) {
    include_once 'config.php';
    do_error("not found", 404, true);
}

$globals['script'] = $script;
if ((include './'.$script) === FALSE) {
    include_once 'config.php';
    do_error("bad request $script", 400, true);
}
```

What I want is to make url redirection, for example: instead of use story.php, I want to use story only. So I have configured the nginx.conf with the following code:

```
index index.php index.html index.htm dispatcher.php;

# Don't serve hidden files.
location ~ /\. {
    deny all;
}

location = /favicon.ico {
    log_not_found off;
}

location / {
    try_files     $uri $uri/ /dispatcher.php?$args;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
  include       fastcgi_params;
  fastcgi_index dispatcher.php;
  fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;

  fastcgi_pass  127.0.0.1:19761;

  # Prevent arbitrary code execution by third parties with
  # try_files directive.
  # http://wiki.nginx.org/Pitfalls#Passing_Uncontrolled_Requests_to_PHP
  try_files     $uri =404;
}
```

But it does not works, when I'am in the web page and go to url/story, it remains on index.php although the url changes. ¿What Am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: you want all requests redirect to dispatcher.php or only some

Comment: all requests. I have show only a piece of code from the entire dispatcher.php

I know that this code worked in another server: `location / {
try_files $uri /dispatcher.php$uri?$args;
}

location ~ .php {
include php_fastcgi;
}`

But no in my actual server..